# print particular items in liferay

Tags: spring, jsp, liferay, portlet

I have a print button. When I will click that button it will print that page. It's displaying everything. I don't want to display everything only particular things. Any help?

```
<input type="button" value=" Print this page "onclick="window.print(); return false;" style="margin-left:300px"/>
```

the output displays the liferay menu logo and lots of things. I tried to use @media print and @media screen css properties. screen css is working but the media print css is not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Build your own theme plugin and develop the @print css part as you want.